# Is possible to create a MS Office com add-in using .Net 5 and an unmanaged shim?

Tags: vsto, office-addins, .net-5, comaddin

Since VSTO has yet not been ported to .NET Core, can I do it the old fashioned way and create a unmanaged shim to load the CLR and host the managed .Core 5 add-in?

My particular use case is an Outlook COM add-in that is currently built using VSTO against .NET framework 4.7 but I want to start leveraging .NET 5. In terms of interaction with Outlook, it just adds some buttons on the Ribbon and makes a few calls into the Outlook object model. I don't need to do anything like VSTO document based add-in in Excel for example.

I don't want to down the JS path as there is quite a bit of C# code that would need to be ported.

I found this https://github.com/jozefizso/COMShimWizard/releases which shows how to do it with the .NET framework, and am assuming its pretty close if not identical to what the shim wizard did back in VS 2010.

Since I need to load .NET 5 I believe to load the CLR I will need to do something along the lines of what is outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting.

Before I dig further into it, is the approach likely to work? In particular, will in be possible to do  necessary COM gymnastics to instantiate the managed components?

And assuming all this is feasible, will this be more or less equivalent to what VSTO does for .NET framework 4.x, i.e. is it less safe or performant in any way or will there be any functionality that won't be available compared with an add-in built with VSTO?

**Update 1**

I did some more research which raised some additional potential issues.

1. For the .NET framework case, once a class has been loaded into the CLR it is relatively easy to "unwrap" the returned reference to get a COM pointer which can be used to access COM interfaces that the type implements. It is not clear to me how this can be done when loading the .NET Core runtime using netfxr interface.
2. .NET Core does not have the concept of app domains, does that mean the multiple add-ins loaded into the Core runtime would not be isolated, or there a way to achieve some degree of isolation? From what I have read it seems that maybe their heaps would at least be isolated but I'm not sure.

**Update 2**

From reading this https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/COM-activation.md it seems that in Core, requests to types in assemblies as COM servers will result in auto loading the Core runtime (if it isn't already loaded) and create the object in a separate AssemblyLoadContext so maybe a shim is not needed at all? On the other hand it seems that if the Core runtime is already loaded and the version does match what is required by type you are trying to create, then the type will fail to load, so that seem to be a problem...